# sending file through sockets python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, file-transfer

I'm trying to send files through sockets but my server is hanging when the file is sent completely. I tried a lot of way but here is my code.

Client :

```
def download_file(self, file_name):
    with open(file_name, "rb") as file:
        while True:
            l = file.read(64)
            if not l:
                break
            self.s.sendall(l)
```

Server :

```
def download_file(self, file_name):
    downloading = True
    with open(file_name, "wb") as file:
        while downloading:
            l = self.client_socket.recv(64)
            if not l:
                print("downloaded")
                downloading = False
            file.write(l)
```

It seems to work until the file is complete, but then my server never goes to the "if not l:" part, it just keeps hanging waiting for data...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `self.s.close()` in the client. Currently the server has no indication that not more data follow, so it must wait for more to come.

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to do the same thing without closing the connection ? Because I want to be able to do other stuff from my server still with this client connected

Comment: Nevermind i added a message at the end of function in the client and stopped the loop in server if this particular message is received. And it works

Comment: Let's hope that _this particular message_ isn't by chance contained in the file. I'm sure you can find an even better way.